# Why can't I run Webpack with React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

For several days, I am trying to install webpack with React. I used several tutorials but I can' t still install it. Recently, I used [this tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) but in the last step, when I try to run `webpack` I get an error:

The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli.
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
-> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D

Then, I run `npm install webpack-cli -D`, but it doesn't help and I don't know how to resolve that problem. When I try to only install webpack I receive the same error. Thanks for advices.

package.json and webpack.config.js content:

```
{
  "name": "proj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.0.40",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.4",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10"
  }
}

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
};
```

Comment: Thats probably because the handbook is integrated with webpack v3 and on webpack v4 there was a separation and webpack-cli was introduced. try to install webpack v3 or follow the migration guide https://github.com/webpack/webpack/wiki/Changelog-WIP

Comment: Add package.json and webpack config to your question

Comment: Same for me. On the other project with webpack4.0.1 works a few days ago, I can cmd: webpack-dev-server. But  whenever I cmd: npm -i webpack-cli, I get "No git binary found in $PATH"

Comment: With it I have the same problem. Can not run `npm run-script build` where I have instruction to install webpack.

Comment: @Choco Lee I have that same error when I run command in vs code console. Please try to do it in `cmd`.

Comment: I try to do the exactly same thing today and this time I'm able to install it. With webpack4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solve my problem. First of all, I deleted `"webpack-cli": "^2.0.10"` from my `package.json`. Then I install `npm install webpack@3.0.0` and add to `package.json`: 
`"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },`
 Now I can run my webpack by `npm run-script build`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try install Webpack^4.1.0, webpack-cli^2.0.10

```
npm i --save-dev webpack@4.1.0 webpack-cli@2.0.10
```